# How to deal with ! x has insufficient unique values to support 10 knots: reduce k.?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam

I have the following code for ggplot.

```
ggplot(sample_info_, aes(GA, BW, color = Age_group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 3)) +
  facet_wrap(~ race_detail)
```

The plot would like this,

[image: Plot Screenshot]

It is clear that the `geom_smooth` fails to add a line to the panels of Ethnicity Laos and Guamanian by giving an error saying,

> Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`
> Caused by error in `smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec()`:
> ! x has insufficient unique values to support 3 knots: reduce k.

The error is not solved for any value of `k`. So, I want to handle this error and use other method  in `geom_smooth` for only those panels where `gam` method fails. In this case, it is Laos and Guamanian.

Any suggestions about how this can be done? Or any other solution to deal with this problem? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Instead of indiviual models for each group, I would fit a [hierarchical GAM](https://peerj.com/articles/6876/) to all data and plot predictions.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for your suggestion. I will go through the article you shared.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have your data set, but I have created one with the same structure and names as your own, which replicates the problem (see below). If we plot this with ggplot, using your exact code, we get the same warning and a similar plot:

```r
ggplot(sample_info_, aes(GA, BW, color = Age_group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 3)) +
  facet_wrap(~ race_detail)
#> Warning messages:
#> 1: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`
#> Caused by error in `smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec()`:
#> ! x has insufficient unique values to support 3 knots: reduce k.
```

[image]

Our warning comes because there are not enough data points for young people in `race_group` "f".

To get round this, you can define your own `method` that switches between a `gam` and, say, an `lm` depending on the data size (if there are fewer than 5 data points we use an `lm` instead of a `gam`:

```r
mymethod <- function(formula, data, weights, ...) {
  if(nrow(data) < 5) return(lm(y ~ x, data = data, ...))
  else  mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 3), data = data, ...)
}
```

And we can use it like this:

```r
ggplot(sample_info_, aes(GA, BW, color = Age_group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = mymethod) +
  facet_wrap(~ race_detail) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 4000))
```

[image]

Note that we now get `gam` smooths where the data can support it, and `lm` otherwise.

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)
GAs <- abs(rnorm(200, 8, 5))^0.1 * 50
GAs <- (GAs - min(GAs))
GAs <- GAs/max(GAs)
GAs <- GAs * 15 + 28
GAs <- round(GAs)
dfs <- lapply(GAs, function(x) data.frame(BW = 2 * abs(rnorm(x, 30*x, 10*x)), 
                                          GA = x))
df <- do.call('rbind', dfs)
df$Age_group <- sample(c('12-23', '24-48', '49-72', '73-168'), nrow(df), 
                       prob = c(0.1, 20, 8, 4), TRUE)
df$race_detail <- sample(letters[1:18], nrow(df), TRUE) 
sample_info_ <- df
```

Comment: Hi Allan, the solution you posted is what I was looking for. Thank you much for helping.